# Inconsistent sonar reports

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I ran sonar analysis on a project in two ways

1. From command prompt using `sonar-runner -X` command
2. As a maven goal using `sonar:sonar`(Java 1.8) and `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar` (java 1.6)

Both scans resulted in two different reports. I don't know why this happened.

Below is my development environment configuration

Maven: 3.0.5
Sonarqube: 3.0.1
Sonar-runner: 2.4
Eclipse: Kepler
Java: 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, my mistake. While analysing from command prompt sonar.source is set to scr. So sonar analysed test code also.

Where as mvn sonar:sonar analysed only src/main/java